# Docker for Windows Swarm IIS Service with Win10 Insider running but unreachable

Tags: windows, docker, docker-swarm, docker-for-windows, docker-desktop

I'm currently experimenting with Swarm Services with Docker for Windows. The new Win10 Insider build supports overlay networking for Windows containers and I was pleased to see my IIS service actually starting. The only issue i came across is that i can not reach the service in the browser, despite trying multiple things such as different ports and networks. The command issued is as following:

```
docker service create --name webfarm -p 80:80 microsoft/iis
```

I have also tried to use the `--network` flag to try different networks and I have made sure to test all IP addresses visible in the `docker service inspect webfarm` command.

`docker service ps webfarm` does indicate that my service is in state RUNNING and does not have any errors, so i don't know what else i can try. Especially since these commands worked fine on Linux with Apache.

I was wondering if anyone has been able to successfully create a service using Windows Containers on the Windows Insider build (15046), and if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, i found this actually is not supported yet.

The following source states:

"At the moment only DNS round robin is implemented as described in the Microsoft blog post. You cannot use to publish ports externally right now. More to come in the near future." (https://stefanscherer.github.io/docker-swarm-mode-windows10/)

And indeed, the blogposts states the following:
"Currently, Windows supports DNS Round-Robin load balancing between services. The routing mesh for Windows Docker hosts is not yet supported, but will be coming soon. Users seeking an alternative load balancing strategy today can setup an external load balancer (e.g. NGINX) and use Swarm’s publish-port mode to expose container host ports over which to load balance." (https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/virtualization/2017/02/09/overlay-network-driver-with-support-for-docker-swarm-mode-now-available-to-windows-insiders-on-windows-10/)

I guess I'll have to wait for this feature, in the meantime I will use the alternative.

Comment: Would the temporary workaround for this be to host the swam in a mixed-os (Win/*Nix) environment? Such that service is hosted from a Linux swarm and workers are windows VMs?